# Manage multiple tabs with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, automation, click, bookmarklet

Suppose I have a JavaScript bookmarklet. When I press this button I would like it to open three predefined URLs and perform an action (clicking the logout button, for example) on each one. If I were doing this with only one site, I could do `window.open("http://stackoverflow.com","_self")` and then `document.getElementById('logout').click()`

Is there a way I can have this action performed simultaneously in different tabs? If not, how would I go about switching tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Switching tabs is beyond what content-level JavaScript has security permissions to do. As far as one JavaScript instance is concerned, there only exists one tab (`window`).

You would need to write an extension for your browser of choice.

If you're writing for Chrome, [check out some documentation on the APIs for tab manipulation with extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs).